# Restart loop after phone reset

Tags: nokia-lumia-930, reset, soft-reset

I have Lumia 930 with Windows Phone 8.1. Today after complete reset phone will not turn on correctly.

- I turn on phone with power key and have cogs animation with progress bar.
- The progress bar stops at 20%.
- After 5-10 minutes phone show ":-(" face and restart.
- Process run one more time

I try to use Nokia Software Recovery Tool but program does not want find my phone.

Can someone help me?

PS. Sorry for my english...

Comment: Have you tried a soft reset? (Hold down Power+Volume-Down until it restarts.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this sequence:

1.Turn off your Lumia device.

2.Press and hold the power button to start your Lumia device.

3.When your Lumia device starts, it displays the Microsoft or Nokia logo. At this instant, release the power button, then press and hold the volume up button. This step should be done quickly.

4.After a few seconds, an image composed of a white lightning and a white gear wheel appear on the screen of your Lumia device. At this instant, release the volume up button.

5.Connect your Lumia device at your PC, this one should simply detect it.

If that goes to the lightning/gear icon you can definitely reflash the phone. Probably by plugging into WPRT at that point.

Tested and taken from [WindowsCentral](http://forums.windowscentral.com/nokia-lumia-830/385342-lumia-830-bricked-after-installing-10536-how-can-i-unbrick.html)